# how to check whether user is login at itunes in iphone or not for in app purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have few queries about in app purchase in iOS. I have 4 in-app for user each with other group. All are auto renewable. Now I had purchased one in-app for user1 then user1 sign out from the app. and user2 is login. and now user 2 is doing in-app.

1. Now user 2 is prompted to enter the password of user1 account. How to stop it?
2. How to refresh `[NSBundle mainBundle].appStoreReceiptURL` on signOut so that user 2 gets his own appStoreReceiptUrl.
3. If the user 2 is not signed then how to prompt them to login at iTunes ?

Comment: purchase and subscriptions should be ONLY linked to their App Store account.